# Can't add image to postgresql

Tags: java, spring, image

I'm creating shop on Spring Boot and i need images for my products. I have a table

```
create table if not exists products
(
    id     bigint unique primary key not null,
    name   varchar(50)               not null unique,
    price  varchar(50)               not null,
    serial varchar(50)               not null unique,
    picture bytea
);
```

I have simple entity class for products, also repository and service with basic CRUD methods. all  my products are being inserted to table on program startup from main class

```
@Bean
CommandLineRunner runner(ProductService productService, UserService userService) {
    return args -> {
        productService.saveProduct(new Products(11L, "black mask", 100, 11111, "img/mask_black.png")); //and so on
```

my images are saved in resources/static/img/, but it's not working. I read a lot of answers in related topics, but it's not helpful. What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing filepath (which is string type) for byte array, that's the reason for failing.
First load file object using file path, then convert file to byte array byte[] and then pass that byte[] for persisting.

Example:

```
byte[] array = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/path/to/file"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add it, but i recomend to you create a new table image and persist image and data splitedly, althougth on any select you will retriving a lot of unecessary data

```
create table if not exists products
(
    id        bigint unique primary key not null,
    name      varchar(50)               not null unique,
    price     varchar(50)               not null,
    serial    varchar(50)               not null unique,
    pictureId bigint                    not null
);

create table if not exists productPictures
(
    id      bigint unique primary key not null,
    picture bytea                     not null
);
```

And put some constraint between them.

By the way look postgres documentation for https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-binary.html